# Android filter sqlite results for listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, filtering

Hi im having problems with the syntax for the query string for filtering results for a listview showing sqlite results on Android.

```
  public Cursor searchByInputText(String inputText) throws SQLException {
      String query = "SELECT _id as _id," +" title" +  " from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + "title" + " LIKE '" + inputText + "';";
      //String query = "SELECT _id as _id," +" title" +  " from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + "title" + " LIKE '" + inputText + "';";
      //String query =  "SELECT _id from " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE title="+inputText;
      Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id as _id, title from "+TABLE_NAME +" where title like " + inputText,null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        System.out.println(query);
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

I have tried so many solutions, but none seem to work for me, any sugggestions would be great.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `String` type in `where` clause, it should be in single quotes.

```
where title like '%" + inputText +"'"
```

Comment: thanks for the rapid response, that stopped the crash but no results are being shown in the listview.

Comment: @n4zg: That is different issue. This answer only helps in how to fix your SQL. Please make sure you are getting data from SQLite first. Once you are done with this step, check why that is not being set to listview. Refer few tutorials.

Comment: i can see the sqlite data in the listview but i need to filter the results, i have tested the query without adding the parameter for the search and i can see the results.. is this query correct now then   Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id as _id, title from "+TABLE_NAME +" where title like '" + inputText +"'",null); ?

Comment: I see that you are using like in query, if you use like, you should add % symbol too. See updated query. See more details about like syntax here http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Comment: i got the following wrror with that android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id as _id, title from allfeed where title like %'f*'

Comment: Please make sure % is inside single quote and read the link posted in my other comment. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help that didnt work.. i will continue searching for a solution..